# List of leftover words from two text files

Tags: php

I have two different text files. I would like to "compare" the first text file from the second text file. And eventually, list the words which are on the first text file, but not on the second text file as result.

If some words are on the first text file and on the second text file, it won't list them as result.

I have very very basic knowledge in php and would need some help to make this script. All i know for now is i should use if stripos.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried something ? Show your code!

Comment: As @Rizier123 said, what have you tried? Stack overflow is for specific questions on how to solve specific programming problems; not for the general solution to a larger problem.

Comment: Right tool for the job? Does this absolutely need to be done in php? Asking because on *nix this can be achieved with a very short combo of `tr -cs ...` (to keep each word in a line), `sort -u` (to sort and uniquify), and `comm -23` (to leave words from output1 and not in output2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty basic approach, it might not be great for larger files.

```
$files = array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt');
$words = array();
foreach ($files as $key => $file)
{
  $text = file_get_contents($file);
  $words[$key] = explode(' ', str_replace("\n", ' ', $text));
  $words[$key] = array_unique($words[$key]);
}

$diff_words = array_diff($words[0], $words[1]);

var_dump($diff_words);
```

There are MANY things that could go wrong depending on the format and contents of the files you're feeding in, for example punctuation, window line breaks, capitalization, so be patient as you work through those problems according to your own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can write each file lines in an array for each and compare them, if the file is not too large.

```
$file1 = file("file1.txt");
$file2 = file("file2.txt");
var_dump(array_diff($file1, $file2));
```

Work with the array which *array_diff* returns. There is no need to use *array_diff*, you can go through one array with foreach on your own.